# 4500x ios upgrade

Tags: cisco-ios

I have a Cisco 4500x-32SFP (with Enterprise License) with cat4500e-universalk9.SPA.03.04.04.SG.151-2.SG4.bin ios and i want to upgrade it to cat4500e-universal.SPA.03.11.03a.E.152-7.E3a.bin which is suggested by cisco :

1. if i want to do this upgrade, do i lost my license key? can i perform an upgrade safely  without any worry about license key ?
2. i just do the simple upgrade process?

Comment: It's always a good idea to keep backups of any licenses -- esp. non-factory licenses. Systems do fail, and it's nice to have proof of what the device had.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy your new IOS to device, then

```
conf t
boot system flash bootflash: cat4500e-universal.SPA.03.11.03a.E.152-7.E3a.bin
do write
```

Check your configuration

```
do show run | i boot
```

If you see there two or more boot statement, then delete all old statements:

```
no boot system flash bootflash:cat4500e-universalk9.SPA.03.04.04.SG.151-2.SG4.bin
do write
```

Now you should reboot your device.

```
reload
```

Comment: do i need to backup license ? becaue i have enterprise license i do not want to lost my license, upgrade ios will keep the enterprise license?

Comment: You won't loose license with update. Check your license after update and if there is any problem, you can boot previous IOS.